# CSS - Elements visible outside of overflow - Glitching - Weird visual bug I can't explain

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, aurelia, visual-glitch

Hi I've never seen a bug like this and I simply don't know where to start. Can anyone tell me what you think? Is it Javascript, CSS, the Browser or my Computer?

The best I can do to explain the bug is just ask that you watch the video.

What I am showing in Video 1 is a container that has a max-height. When it reaches that height it gets an overflow. When I start scrolling you will see the bug at the bottom of the screen.

This is an intermittent bug and sometimes when I scroll the "+" icon at the top also glitches (I have shown this in Video 2)

The icons are just background-image PNGs.

The browser is Chrome - Version 60.0.3112.113

[Video 1](https://streamable.com/29w5d)

[Video 2](https://streamable.com/th23c)

Edit (19 Aug 2017): I have added a third video that I think illustrates the problem more clearly

[Video 3](https://streamable.com/sbaqn)

Edit (19 Aug 2017): I am using `display: grid` and `position: sticky` in my CSS. My first guess was that it's a bug related to those properties... but even after eliminating them I still have the same problem

Comment: funnily enough, the videos you posted don't play in Chrome, as they require a flash plugin. Maybe https://streamable.com/ would work

Comment: Thanks... I have fixed it so it's hosted on streamable now

Comment: One of my colleagues thinks it may have something to do with `z-index` so I'll have to refactor it a bit and see how it goes

Comment: I have asked other colleagues to test this and it seems to be only happening on my computer, even though we all have the same browser version. The only difference I can think of is that they have dedicated GPUs whereas mine is onboard.

No clue if that would make a difference but anyway ** shrugs **.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain exactly why this problem occurs, but my guess is that it somehow relates to the z-index of the child elements. For some reason the browser is getting confused and it glitches out when it tries to repaint those elements.

I have added `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` to the child elements and this has resolved the issue.